# How can I figure out what the total ram of the system currently is?

Tags: nodeos, ram

Is there a way to know what the total system ram currently is?

Is it the balance in bytes?

```
$ ./cleos -u http://localhost:8080/ get table eosio eosio rammarket
{
  "rows": [{
      "supply": "10000000000.0000 RAMCORE",
      "base": {
        "balance": "67296295696 RAM",
        "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
      },
      "quote": {
        "balance": "1021151.0869 EOS",
        "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
      }
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the base balance is the balance of unused RAM in bytes. To get the total ram, check the `global` table instead:

```
$ cleos get table eosio eosio global

{
  "rows": [{
      "max_block_net_usage": 1048576,
      "target_block_net_usage_pct": 1000,
      "max_transaction_net_usage": 524288,
      "base_per_transaction_net_usage": 12,
      "net_usage_leeway": 500,
      "context_free_discount_net_usage_num": 20,
      "context_free_discount_net_usage_den": 100,
      "max_block_cpu_usage": 200000,
      "target_block_cpu_usage_pct": 1000,
      "max_transaction_cpu_usage": 150000,
      "min_transaction_cpu_usage": 100,
      "max_transaction_lifetime": 3600,
      "deferred_trx_expiration_window": 600,
      "max_transaction_delay": 3888000,
      "max_inline_action_size": 4096,
      "max_inline_action_depth": 4,
      "max_authority_depth": 6,
      "max_ram_size": "74168411136",          // <---------- THIS ONE
      "total_ram_bytes_reserved": "49952886463",
      "total_ram_stake": "27270984038",
      "last_producer_schedule_update": "2018-08-16T20:21:12.000",
      "last_pervote_bucket_fill": "1534449856500000",
      "pervote_bucket": 224450634,
      "perblock_bucket": 32393230,
      "total_unpaid_blocks": 84215,
      "total_activated_stake": "3719091849385",
      "thresh_activated_stake_time": "1529505892000000",
      "last_producer_schedule_size": 21,
      "total_producer_vote_weight": "14267703671640342528.00000000000000000",
      "last_name_close": "2018-08-07T06:13:30.000"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```